# why isn't .getFile() loading image

Tags: java

NEW Update

Have now done a different thing and got more than one image to appear in the JFrame at one time, but importantly how do I equally space the images  horizontally?

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String[] list = {"test/Spidey.jpg","test/mandarin.jpg","test/jaws.jpg"};
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    
    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    

    
    URL myurl = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource(list[i]);
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(myurl);
    JLabel l = new JLabel(img);
    
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.add(l);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
    
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Got it working like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    ClassLoader theClass = spidey.class.getClassLoader();
    URL myurl = theClass.getResource("test/Spidey.jpg");
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(myurl);
    JLabel l = new JLabel(img);
    
    
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.add(l);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
    
    }
}
```

Almost the same as before, but this time added ImageIcon

Comment: Please share a larger code snippet and what is the line number 16 where exception is thrown.

Comment: To me it seems like the path to the image file is incorrect. Are you sure your "Spidey.jpg" in the correct location?

Comment: Have you tried URL imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Spidey.jpg");

Answer (score 2):

To display image in JLabel you must use JLabel(Icon i); But here the getFile() method you used will only return the name of the file.
Try the following

```
URL url = new URL("your desired url");
Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Comment: Now it says: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: test/Spidey.jpg

Comment: @user12099646 - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Comment: The only solution for this is to make sure that the url you have passed is legal, with a proper protocol.

The best way to do it is validating the URL before you proceed with your program. For validation you can use regular expression or other libraries that provide url validators.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-handle-malformedurlexception-in-java
You can go through this link and solve the issue

Comment: Yeah I found this useful

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following line:

```
ClassLoader theClass = spidey.class.getClassLoader();
```

It should be

```
ClassLoader theClass = Test.class.getClassLoader();
```

You can also write it in one line as follows:

```
URL myurl = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/IMG_20191230_153117.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you posted, file `Spidey.jpg` needs to be in the same directory as file `spidey.class`.

Method `getResource()` is returning null. Hence variable `imageURL` is null. Hence this part of your code is throwing `NullPOinterException`:

```java
imageURL.getFile()
```

### EDIT

```java
Class<?> theClass = spidey.class;
URL url = theClass.getResource("Spidey.jpg");
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
JLabel l = new JLabel(img);
```

Refer to [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) in the *Java Tutorials*

Comment: OK put file in same directory, now  output  in JFrame is the path name ie /Users....../spidey.jpg

There is no image....